# PHP str_replace with wild card?

Tags: php

I know how to use str_replace for simple tasks, like this...

```
$Header = str_replace('<h2>Animals</h2>', '<h3>Animals</h3>', $Header);
```

But imagine an article stored in a database that includes the following headers:

```
<h3>Animals</h3>
<h3>Plants</h3>
```

And you want to change them to this:

```
<h3><span class="One">Animals</span></h3>
<h3><span class="One">Plants</span></h3>
```

Is there a way to turn the value between the tags (e.g. Animals, Plants, Minerals, etc.) into a wild card, something like this?:

```
$Title = str_replace('<h3>*</h3>', '<h3><span style="One">*</span></h3>', $Title);
```

Or I should ask "What's the best way?" It looks like there are ways to do it, but I'd like to try and find a simple PHP solution before I start wrestling with regular expressions.

Comment: 1) You should do HTML manipulation using an HTML parser/DOM library. 2) You're looking for regular expressions.

Comment: 3) You don’t necessarily need wildcards here, you could just replace `<h3>` with `<h3><span style="One">` and `</h3>` with `</span></h3>`. [Although, 1) trumps 2) and 3).]

Comment: Yes, I thought about that. The only problem is that the latter would replace ALL h3 closing tags, including some that I might not want to target. I could solve that problem by putting something like </h3><!--h3--> in my database to serve as a handle.

Comment: Or... you could parse the HTML and manipulate the DOM with very precise XPath queries or simple tree traversal...

Comment: If you don't want to use the `DOMDocument` library, the answer to your question is that you use regular expressions to do pattern matching and replacement. See `preg_replace`. Regular expressions should be a general part of any experienced programmer's toolkit.

Comment: I'm learning to use DOMDocument right now - along with jQuery and half a dozen other things. jQuery is relatively easy, but some people apparently discourage it because of users who might have JavaScript disabled on their browsers. That's why I have a preference for DOMDocument - but if there's an easier way, I'll take it. ;)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use the `str_replace()` technique that has been suggested in the primary comments, but I believe [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) using regular expressions is the best practice for wildcard replacements.

```
<?php
$str = <<<EOD

<h3>Animals</h3>
<h3>Plants</h3>

EOD;

$str = preg_replace('/<h3>(.*?)<\/h3>/', '<h3><span class="One">$1</span></h3>', $str);

echo $str;
```

Comment: helped me with changing value of data- attribute. Thanks.

Comment: See http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/36e30fb7cac613bd26bb8d8e57d2d2d518e6c73e for a working example of this