# preg/str replace with wild card php

Tags: php, string, escaping, wildcard

want to repalce /randomword/ (wildcard) with /page-1/
so url would be replaced as  http://www.example.com/randomword/page-1/fixed/index?ok=as

```
$url="http://www.example.com/randomword/fixed/index?ok=as";


$url= preg_replace('//(.*?)/fixed', '/randomword/page-1/fixed', $url);
```

not working the / confuses me when i dont know when to escape it

(read [PHP str_replace with wild card?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28377773/php-str-replace-with-wild-card))

Comment: Regex's need delimiters in PHP. http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php

Comment: i read it but seems overly complicated with no examples

Comment: See examples here, http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php. The first `/` is the opening delimiter the last `/` is the closing one. Everything inbetween is the regex. From the first link note: `If the delimiter needs to be matched inside the pattern it must be escaped using a backslash. If the delimiter appears often inside the pattern, it is a good idea to choose another delimiter in order to increase readability.`... so `~/(.*?)/fixed~` i think would resolve your issue. You also might prefer any non `/` over `(.*?)`.

Comment: If `/fixed/` is constant you could just `str_replace` that by prepending the new dir on it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What Delimiter to use for preg\_replace in PHP (replace working outside of PHP but not inside)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4322718/what-delimiter-to-use-for-preg-replace-in-php-replace-working-outside-of-php-bu)

Answer (score 1):

There is no wild card for str_replace(); you want to use preg_replace() instead.

Try this:

```
$url= preg_replace('~/(.*?)/fixed~', '/randomword/page-1/fixed', $url);
```

In addition, here's a great tool to help you build regular expressions in different languages: http://txt2re.com/

Further reading:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php
- [PHP str_replace with wild card?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28377773/php-str-replace-with-wild-card)
- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4322718/what-delimiter-to-use-for-preg-replace-in-php-replace-working-outside-of-php-bu

Big thanks to @chris85 who supplied most of the information for this answer!